# how a VBO position would change sampler2D value?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

It took me sometimes to figure out where was my problem,  and when I did I've tried everything I though of ... but I can't find a solution, this problem look very weird to me.

I've boiled down my problem to almost full straight opengl code for you to help me here.

The idea is, I'm drawing a quad with a white texture in a "layer" (framebuffer+texture)

Then I use this layer as a texture to draw a (the same) quad to the window,

using the same shader in each drawcall.

The problem is:

as long as my VBO "position" (first two floats of vertices) range from -1 to +1 , I get a nice full white frame,

```
std::vector<float> vertices = { 1,1, 1,1,   1,-1, 1,0,   -1,-1, 0,0,  -1,1, 0,1 };
```

[image]

BUT BUT BUT when the VBO "position" range from -1 to .5, I would hope for a 75% of the screen in full white, but I get half screen, half intensity

```
std::vector<float> vertices = { .5,.5, 1,1,   .5,-1, 1,0,   -1,-1, 0,0,  -1,.5, 0,1 };
```

[image]

and finale scenration VBO "position range from 0 to -1, I 'd hope for a quarter of the swreen is white, but I get fullblack

```
std::vector<float> vertices = { 0,0, 1,1,   0,-1, 1,0,   -1,-1, 0,0,  -1,0, 0,1 };
```

[image]

```
// create framebuffer to draw in
GLuint buffer,fb;
glGenTextures(1, &buffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, buffer);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, buffer, 0);

// create white texture
GLuint white;
unsigned char white_data[4] = {255,255,255,255};
glGenTextures(1, &white);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, white);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 1, 1, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &white_data[0]);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

// create Quad
GLuint vao, vertices_buffer,indices_buffer;
std::vector<float> vertices = { 1,1, 1,1,   1,-1, 1,0,   -1,-1, 0,0,  -1,1, 0,1 };
std::vector<int> indices = {0,1,3,1,2,3};
glGenBuffers(1, &vertices_buffer); glGenBuffers(1, &indices_buffer); glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  vertices.size()*sizeof(float) , &vertices[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW );
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size()*sizeof(int) , &indices[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW );
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4*sizeof(float), (GLvoid *) (0 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4*sizeof(float), (GLvoid *) (2 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

the render loop

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, white);
shader.use();

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements ( GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, buffer);
shader.use();

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements ( GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

the shader

```
#version 330 core

// VERTEX 
layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 texcoord;

void main() {

    texcoord = texCoord;
    
    gl_Position = vec4(position,0,1);

}

// FRAGMENT
in vec2 texcoord;
out vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main() {

  color = texture(tex,texcoord);

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the format parameter of `glTexImage2D` for the white texture be `GL_RGBA`?

Comment: Have the default framebuffer and `fb` the same size?

Comment: @ BDL good observation, well it MUST not, but it could, in my case it does not change a thing &
@Rabbid76, yes they do

Comment: Next guess: You have a minification filter set on the framebuffer texture which requires a mipmap (GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR), but you do not regenerate the mipmaps after rendering to the FBO. When downsampling, the white level0 mipmap is interpolated with the (still) black level 1 mipmap. Try to change the `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `GL_LINEAR` on the `buffer` texture.

Comment: and the winner is : BDL ! yep that s what it was..... damn I though I started getting my head arround openGL but now I remember I actually put the mimap part kinda  under the carpet for a while  ^^

Answer (score 2):

[@BDL found the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68941830/how-a-vbo-position-would-change-sampler2d-value/68943047#comment121841262_68941830):

> You have a minification filter set on the framebuffer texture which requires a mipmap (GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR), but you do not regenerate the mipmaps after rendering to the FBO. When downsampling, the white level0 mipmap is interpolated with the (still) black level 1 mipmap. Try to change the `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `GL_LINEAR` on the `buffer` texture.

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_complete_texture

> The default GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER state is GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR. And because OpenGL defines the default GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL to be 1000, OpenGL will expect there to be mipmap levels defined